# Django CBV - change FBV to CBV

Tags: django

Writing my first "real" django project I realized that my views are really huge. I try to convert it into CBV (as additional django training). Here are my fbv views:

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    categories = Category.objects.select_related()
    subcategories = SubCategory.objects.all()
    context['categories'] = categories
    context['subcategories'] = subcategories
    return render(request, 'mainapp/index.html', context)


def category(request, category_name_slug):
    context = {}
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
        subcategory = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=category)
        context['subcategories'] = subcategory
        context['category'] = category
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Category doesn't exist")
    return render(request, 'mainapp/category.html', context)


def subcategory(request, category_name_slug, subcategory_name_slug):

    context = {}
    form = SiteAddForm(initial={'url': 'http://'})
    context['form'] = form
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
        subcategory = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=category
                                                 ).get(slug=subcategory_name_slug)
        sites = Site.objects.filter(subcategory=subcategory, is_active=True)
        context['subcategory'] = subcategory
        context['category'] = category
        context['sites'] = sites
    except (SubCategory.DoesNotExist, Category.DoesNotExist):
        raise Http404("Nie ma takiej strony")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SiteAddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            siteurl = form.cleaned_data['url']
            context['siteurl'] = siteurl
            try:
                page = AddNewSite(siteurl)
            except:
                print('ERRROR')
                context['Error'] = "URL is not responding"
                return render(request, 'mainapp/subcategory.html', context)
            title = page.title()
            description = page.description()
            keywords = page.keywords()
            if page.check_url_in_database():
                context['Error'] = "Site already in database"
                return render(request, 'mainapp/subcategory.html', context)
            else:
                form_extended = SiteAddFormFull(initial={'url': siteurl, 'name':
                                                     title, 'description':
                                                     description, 'keywords':
                                                     keywords})
            context['form_extended'] = form_extended
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form_extended = SiteAddFormFull(request.POST)
                if form_extended.is_valid():
                    keywords = form_extended.cleaned_data['keywords']
                    name = form_extended.cleaned_data['name']
                    description = form_extended.cleaned_data['description']
                    page.add_site(category, subcategory, keywords,
                                  description, name, siteurl)
                    context['added_site'] = 'Thank you - site was added'
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Dodano!!')

return render(request, 'mainapp/subcategory.html', context)
```

How Can I simpy write my base view (index) using CBV. It should look that way:
Category:
    Sub1
    Sub2
Category2:
    Sub2a
    Sub2b

Should I learn CBV or stay using FBV (it works)? Below are my Category, Subcategory models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True,
                        verbose_name='Category name')
    slug = models.SlugField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category_images',
                          verbose_name="Category image",
                          blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='Description',
                               verbose_name="Category description")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def image_thumb(self):
        if self.image:
            return '<img src="/media/%s" width="40" height="40" />' % (self.image)
        else:
            return('')
    image_thumb.short_description = 'Thumb'
    image_thumb.allow_tags = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'Category',
        related_name='subcategory',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(SubCategory, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Subcategories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: this is more like asking us to do it. :) anyway it's pointless to convert FBV to CBV just for the sake of doing so

Comment: No, it is not. I would like to get any advice, clues, whatever... Maybe in your opinion my fbv is good enough... I don't know, I am only asking.

Comment: "Maybe in your opinion ..." already one flag for primarily opinon based

Comment: CBV are no magic bullet. If your FBV is a mess, your CBV is gonna be a mess too. If you want to improve your code, start by improving your FBV. When you think your FBV is in a good shape, you can try refactoring it to a CBV if that's what you want.

Comment: Converting FBV to CBV is good practice and should help learn the details of the CBV approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an advocate of CBV, it can make life a lot easier when trying to reuse code. There are also a ton of pre-defined generic views that only need a small tweaks for most instances. For your example index, you can use a TemplateView:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "mainapp/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.select_related()
        context['subcategories'] = SubCategory.objects.all()
        return context
```